# Power Bi time picker broken?

Tags: azure, powerbi, timepicker, azure-application-insights

the time picker doesnt seem reliable. it gives drastically different results when i do the "timestamp <= ago(24h)" vs the built in time picker. is there any explanation of this or am i doing something wrong? the documentation has no mention of this. see:
[power bi time picker documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/application-insights-analytics-time-picker/)

my apoligies if the image is not clear enough

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Last 24 hours" in the time picker is equivalent to "timestamp **>=** ago(24h)".

You want all records where their "timestamp" value is **larger or equals** than 24 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

@yonisha, you are partially correct. after reversing the "<" to ">" it still did not work properly for me. in case anyone else ran into this i received this answer per microsofts power bi program manager which i found to work:

"I fell for that one myself at first. Perhaps this syntax is more intuitive: timestamp > now() - 24h"

[image]

[image]